# Tomcat filter does not support asynchrony

Tags: java, asynchronous, tomcat, filter

Such as the title

```
@WebFilter("/*")
@Component
@Slf4j
public class FilterDemo1 implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException, IOException {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                chain.doFilter(req, resp);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("a", e);
            }
        }).start();
     
    }

}
```

Therefore, if there are time-consuming tasks (such as RPC or HTTP) in Tomcat filter, they must wait and cannot be asynchronous

````
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]```


[error][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFYTH.png
````

Answer (score 1):

The `ServletRequest`, `ServletResponse` and `FilterChain` object are valid only on the thread where `doFilter` is called. If you want to use them asynchronously, you need to enable asynchronous processing (cf. [Jakarta EE Tutorial](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#asynchronous-processing-in-servlets)).

`ServletRequest.startAsync()` puts the `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` into asynchronous mode, but `FilterChain` can only be used on the original thread:

> The `service` method is required to run in the same thread as **all** filters that apply to the servlet.

(cf. [Servlet Specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#filter-lifecycle))

Therefore you need to proceed as follow:

1. When a **new** request passes through the filter, you call `ServletRequest.startAsync()` and launch your new thread or use any other executor for your asynchronous filtering (e.g. `AsyncContext.start(Runnable)`),
2. When the asynchronous task is finished, you write the results as request attributes and call `AsyncContext.dispatch()`: this will restart the filter chain from the beginning,
3. When `doFilter` is called again, you use the request's attributes to perform your filtering logic and call `FilterChain.doFilter`

For example you can use something like this:

```java
@WebFilter(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = {"/*"}, dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.REQUEST})
public class Filter1 implements Filter {

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
      switch (request.getDispatcherType()) {
         case REQUEST :
            // First pass: start asynchronous processing
            final AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync();
            new Thread(() -> {
               try {
                  Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                  request.setAttribute("filter1Error", e);
               }
               asyncContext.dispatch();
            }).start();
            break;
         case ASYNC :
            // Second pass: throw or forward
            Exception e = (Exception) request.getAttribute("filter1Error");
            if (e instanceof IOException) {
               throw (IOException) e;
            } else if (e instanceof ServletException) {
               throw (ServletException) e;
            } else if (e != null) {
               throw new ServletException(e);
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            break;
         default :
      }
   }
```